# Why this post http request doesn't work in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do this

`login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.post<User>('api/authenticate', { username, password });
    }`

but this doesn't work, 
also this code works

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('www.google.com/api', { username, password });
}
```

i'm using angular 7, with proxy config

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `login()` function by subscribing the observable you return.

```js
this.login.subscribe(response => {
    // Do your logic here
    // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your base URL setup your first request may just need relative path.
'/api/authenticate' instead of 'api/authenticate'.